# Convergence for symmetric, positive semi-definite operator

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume $u$ is a vector in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^N$, $\|u\|=\sqrt{\langle u, u\rangle}$, where $\langle u, v\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^N u_i v_i$.
I have that $\|u^{k+1}-u\|\leq \|I - c A\|\|u^k-u\|$, where $A$ is symmetric, positive semi-definite operator and $c>0$ is a parameter. Here $\|(I-cA)\|$ is the operator norm of $(I-cA)$.
I know that $\|I - c A\| = \max(|1-c \lambda_\min|,|1-c\lambda_\max|)$, where $\lambda_\min$ and $\lambda_\max$ is the least and the greatest eigenvalue of $A$, respectively. Therefore, we have
$\|I - c A\| = \max(1,|1-c\lambda_\max|)$ and for $c<2/\lambda_\max$ we get $\|u^{k+1}-u\|\leq\|u^k-u\|$.
How to get that  $\|u^{k+1}-u\|< \|u^k-u\|$? Or in general, to show that $\|u^k-u\|\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: I am assuming this as a homework question on applying the contraction theorem (Banach fixed point theorem) to symmetric, positive definite matrices. In this setting, convergence for all $u^0$ is equivalent to $A$ being positive definite. In particular, your last inequality is not sufficient for convergence.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to know that $A$ is not only positive semi-definite but strictly positive. Then  you can always find a sufficiently small $c>0$ such that $\|I-c A\|<1$ and you get convergence.

On the other hand, if $A$ has a zero eigenvalue, then $(I - c A)$ always has $1$ as an eigenvalue and the inequality you start of with is not strong enough to show convergence.

Comment: Yes, but I can not to change the assumption on $A$.

Comment: Is A somehow connected to a transformation taking $u^{k}$ to $u^{k+1}$?